# How can I delegate to a sub object of an object with Moose handles?

Tags: perl, delegates, moose

The [Moose](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose) [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aDelegation) says that I can delegate to the object `thing` easily enough.

```
has 'thing' => (
   ...
   handles => { set_foo => [ set => 'foo' ] },
);

# $self->set_foo(...) calls $self->thing->set('foo', ...)
```

But I really want to delegate to an object on thing, specifically a datetime object

```
has 'thing' => (
   ...
   handles => {
       get_month => { datetime ... },
   },
);

# $self->get_month calls $self->thing->datetime->month;
```

how would I have to construct handles to get it to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
has thing => (
   ...
   handles => {
      get_month => sub { $_[0]->thing->datetime->month },
   },
);
```

Short of adding `datetime_month` to `thing`, you'll have to write your own delegator.

Comment: At this point you're already writing the method yourself and could as well drop the `handles` declaration and just write `sub get_month` manually.

Comment: @rafl, You could do that, but I disagree about it being better to move it out. Specifically, writing it as a delegator conveys information to the reader that you wouldn't get otherwise.

Comment: I also have other handles on the same object that didn't require this level of depth... so it kind of puts them all in the same spot.

Comment: IMO would have been nice to more declaratively delegate to infinite object methods. maybe `method => { method => { method => [ params ] } } }`

Comment: @xenoterracide, That's positively awful. Not only does the params bit breaks the model, it does so in a very inconsistent and very limiting way (i.e. only applies to the inner layer).

Comment: Furthermore, `sub { $_[0]->thing->datetime->get_month }` is *way* more readable than `{ datetime => { month => { get_month => [] } } }`